# Responsive large image in bootstrap

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I was wondering if there was a class I can use to add an image inside a div that can be responsive and resize the image depending on the resolution of the user. The image is around 1300px and extends past the floating nav bar.

Comment: have you tried:http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images

Comment: Missed that part of the docs apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works nicely:

[getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images)

> > Responsive images Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class.
> >     This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that
> >     it scales nicely to the parent element.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```